# How to make one thread object stop the other thread object in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class here that will be used as a thread/Runnable object, the second class below (UseSearch) has a main method that intantiates two instances of the Search class and uses them to create two threads. As you can see, the run method calls the add method that runs the loop depending on the direction passed in. I am looking for a mechanism that will cause one of the threads to stop the other thread's loop from iterating when the other thread has finished running it's iteration. Any help/advise will be highly appreciated. I have seen a similar example but it's far too complex for me to comprehend. - Jevison7x

```
public class Search implements Runnable
{
    int sum;

    boolean direction;

    String name;

    public Search(String n, boolean positive)
    {
         this.direction = positive;
         this.name = n;
    }

    void add()
    {
         if(direction == true)
         {
              for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
              {
                 sum += 1;
                 System.out.println(name+" has "+sum);
              }
         }
         else
         {
              for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
              {
                  sum -= 1;
                  System.out.println(name+" has "+sum);
              }
         }
  }

  public void run()
  {
    add();
  }
}

public class UseSearch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Search s1 = new Search("bob", true);
        Search s2 = new Search("dan", false);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(s1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(s2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread that is doing the iterating needs to test something on each iteration to see if it has been told to stop.  That could be a custom flag (implemented in a variety of ways) or a the thread's `interrupted` flag.

If you are going to use `interrupt`, then Matt Clark's answer is half of the picture.  The other half is that the iterating thread needs to do something like this:

```
    if (Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
        // pause or stop or break out of the loop or whatever
    }
```

... in the body of the relevant loop or loops.

---

Note: there is no *safe* way in Java to stop or pause another thread that is not regularly checking to see if it should stop / pause; i.e. a thread that is not *cooperating*.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer short...
Make the Threads class-wide variables so that each thread has access to the other:

```
Thread t1, t2;

public static void main(String[] args){
    t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            t2.interrupt();
        }
    };

    t2=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            t1.interrupt();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a mechanism that will cause one of the threads to stop the other thread's loop from iterating when the other thread has finished running it's iteration of the loop. This will not make it work in terms of the loop's iteration.